# FIR Filter Design in python

Tags: filters, python, finite-impulse-response

This is mine code for fir_filter_design in python. But I'm getting wrong output for low-pass, band-pass, and high-pass magnitude response.

```
def fir_filter_design(N, cutoff_frequency, window, Fs, ftype):
    omega_c = 2 * np.pi * np.array(cutoff_frequency) / Fs

    h = np.zeros(N)

    for n in range(N):
        omega = (2 * np.pi * n) / N
        if omega == 0:
            h[n] = window[n]
        else:
            if ftype == 'lowpass':
                h[n] = window[n] * (np.sin(omega_c * (N - n)) / (np.pi * (N - n)))
            elif ftype == 'highpass':
                h[n] = window[n] * (np.sin(omega_c * n) / (np.pi * n))
            elif ftype == 'bandpass':
                h[n] = window[n] * ((np.sin(omega_c[1] * (N - n)) / (np.pi * (N - n))) -
                                     (np.sin(omega_c[0] * (N - n)) / (np.pi * (N - n))))
            else:
                raise ValueError("Invalid filter type. Use 'lowpass', 'highpass', or 'bandpass'.")

    return h
```

please suggest corrections.

PS: I'm using kaiser window.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to: explain why you're not using the Numpy or Scipy filter design routines; what results you expected to get; what results you _are_ getting and why you feel the difference is signifciant. If at all possible, show your results graphically either in the time domain, the frequency domain, or both.